# Why does light act differently in miniatures?

Tags: visible-light, shadow

When painting miniatures (like RPG fantasy miniature soldiers)... why is it necessary to paint lights and shadows?

Being a 3D object, shouldn't the natural light be enough to create lights and shadows if the figure is simply painted with plain colours?

Comment: I would also assume that the painting colours are more shiny than the "real" objects and the surfaces are smoother (so also more shiny). For example, the face of a person wearing a black hoodie is in the shadow because the black textile (not only black but also of complex geometry) does not reflect much (from its inside surface to the face). But the paint on a miniature hoodie guy is more shiny, hence does reflects light to the face in spite of being "black"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When objects are very small, every source of illumination will appear to be "extended" - which softens the shadows and makes it harder to see the contours of the surface.

By painting highlights and shadows, you reduce the impact of the extended source. See for example [Why don't fluorescent lights produce shadows?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161406/26969)

Comment: The animations of the question linked are quite clarifying, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably mainly because of two reasons:

1. Psychological reasons. You want to see a lot of details on the sculpture, which it might be difficult to do if it is small unless you paint shadows on it. If you took a close-up photo of a miniature it would probably be easier too fool someone that it was real-sized if it didn't have shadows painted on it.
2. Many materials are semi-translucent and let more light through the thinner they are, so you get [subsurface scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsurface_scattering). Hence, for small figures you might be able to "see through" some parts, especially corners and otherwise thin details, which blurs the boundary between enlightened and shadowed parts somewhat. For this reason you might want to enhance those boundaries on some parts of the figure.